# Add one or multiple modules to multiple courses

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I need to add a course module (assign for example) to a list of existing courses. 
There are too many courses for doing this in each one of them.
I haven't found a way to do it through moodle interface.
Is there any function in Moodle API that allows to do that? Or should I do that through database?

My guess is that I need to add one module as a reference and copy it to other courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `moosh`

https://moosh-online.com/

It's a command line tool that allows you to perform lots of common tasks.

For example, to add an assign activity to a course with id 2

```
moosh activity-add assign 2
```